# What must we remember in October 2020?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Who wears the olive wreath
with who lives in the trash
they do a ballroom martial art
and you heard it more than once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must remember (if you live in a particular country at least) to:

> **VOTE!**

*Who wears the olive wreath*

> The **VICTOR** *wears the laurel wreath* (at least in the context of the ancient Olympic Games...)

*with who lives in the trash*

> [**OSCAR** the Grouch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_the_Grouch) lives in a trash can in *Sesame Street*.

*they do a ballroom martial art*

> The **TANGO** is a ballroom dance.

*and you heard it more than once*

> That would be an **ECHO** (ECHO... echo...)

These are all:

> codewords in the NATO phonetic alphabet, representing the letters V-O-T-E. A message to all you Americans out there! (But don't forget you can do it up until Election Day on November 3...!)